# RibbonCombobox selecting the first Item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, ribbon

Hey i got a viewModel that contains these properties:

```
    private List<Product> _products;

    public List<Product> Products
    {
        get { return _products; }
        set
        {
            _products = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Products");
        }
    }

    Product _selectedProduct;

    public Product SelectedProduct
    {
        get { return _selectedProduct; }
        set
        {
            _selectedProduct = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedProduct");
        }
    }
```

In the View Model Constructor i populate them:

```
         Products = (List<Product>)item;
         if (Products.Count > 0)
             SelectedProduct = Products[0];
```

The XAML looks like:

```
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox Label="Product"  >
                    <ribbon:RibbonGallery   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct,  Mode=TwoWay}"  Command="{Binding ParameterChangeCommand}">
                        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"   />
                    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
                </ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
```

Why the does my ComboBox don't Auto Select the first Itemon startup (btw the combo Box is populated with data correctly)? Later if the selected Item is changed, the combo Box is updated correctly.